# React Navigation fails between 2 stacks

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have the following structure in my `App.tsx`:

```
-- NavigationContainer
   |
   --- RootStackNavigator
       |
       if logged in:
           |
           - AppStackNavigator
             |
             - HomeScreen
       else:
           |
           - AuthStackNavigation
             |
             - LoginScreen
```

After a successful Login I want to navigate to `HomeScreen` but I keep getting an error:

`The action "NAVIGATE" with payload {"name":"AppStackNavigator","params":{"screen":"Home"}} was not handled by navigator. Do you have a screen named "AppStackNavigator"?`

I don't know what am I doing wrong here?

App.tsx code:

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator> 
        {  ! props.isTokenValid 
           ? <RootStack.Screen name = { 'AuthStack' } component={ AuthStackNavigator } />
           : <RootStack.Screen name = { 'AppStack' } component={ AppStackNavigator } />
        }
        </RootStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

AppStack.tsx code:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const AppStackNavigator = () => {

return (
    <AppStack.Navigator>
          <AppStack.Screen name= {'Home'} component={Home}/>
    </AppStack.Navigator>
  );

}
```

AuthStack.tsx:

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthStackNavigator = () => {

return (
      <AuthStack.Navigator>
          <AuthStack.Screen name= {'Login'} component={Login}/>
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );

}
```

When login is successful this is what I try to do:

```
const doLogin = ()=>{
        issueToken(phoneNumber,otp).then(res => { 
            navigation.navigate('AppStackNavigator', {screen:'Home'}) ;
        }).catch(err => alert('what went wrong?'));
    }
```

How can move correctly from `Login` screen to `Home` screen?